# Get certain columns from many to many using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

In a many to many relation i would like only to get certain columns from the Referencia table like Id and Name to populate a selectlist. Problem is that I haven't done this before using Linq and I don't understand what is the best way to do this process.

Here are my models.

```
public class Celula
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string UAP { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MatrizCelulaReferencia> Matrizes { get; set; }
}

public class Referencia
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool IsActivo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MatrizCelulaReferencia> Matrizes { get; set; }
}

public class MatrizCelulaReferencia
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CelulaId { get; set; }
    public Celula Celula { get; set; }


    public int ReferenciaId { get; set; }
    public Referencia Referencia { get; set; }

    public int ObjectivoHora { get; set; }
    public int UAPId { get; set; }
    public UAP UAP { get; set; }

    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my current query

```
   var query = await _context.Referencias
                .Include(r => r.Matrizes)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
                .Where(r => r.Matrizes.Any(c => c.CelulaId == Operador.Celula))
                .Select(x => new Referencia
                {
                    Id = // Referencia Id
                    Nome = // Referencia Name
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Right now it's kinda of a mess because I have no idea how can I select certain columns from Referencia table in this query. I only need the Id and Name

Comment: Your includes are not needed btw, the final select operation makes no use of them and the where clause is run on the database.

Comment: I see, i thought i needed them to connect all data. I suppose they are only needed if i need to select data from them, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` param you're passing to the lambda is a `Referencia` instance, so you'd just do:

```
.Select(x => new Referencia
{
    Id = x.Id
    Nome = x.Nome
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was overcomplicating things and doing Selects and other commands on the navigation property instead of accesing the properties directly like that